# Why won't python3 load this json string?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, encoding, utf-8

I have a string

```
b'{"nonce":"820346305172674795","hash":"CF9558F1AC5AA3F4F3D598BAD50D8E0FD15E536A98095C01AD1BA962BDF342D0E37CF6ED595758B3217CA1986238B10EB729D5C5EBCE1523B41328365E936DBE","encryptedMessage":"ABF47CA76B72388B3CA8F4BF95D199D02835C5AED546CC6A6A35663C312093DB05E3765A00211242770136D7F2391A2A69CCA28B4D9695","signature":"09036C211B6386AD0B1D7EDA14AE4C4C77721916C9AF48E7141049E2773098665776AA4B7CC6E12B4B5BD1FBB3B590F41C6254313BAEBA9293D87769F1A4200468747470733A2F2F3139322E3136382E312E38343A353030302F746F67676C655F646F6F722431"}'
```

that is the `print(str(json_string))` output

when i try `json.loads(json_string)`, it says it can't be a byte array, must be a string

When I try json.

Comment: try `json.load(json_string.decode('utf-8'))`. The `b` in the front indicates that it is a byte array.

Comment: ascii = codecs.decode(optArg, "hex")
            json_string = codecs.decode(ascii, "utf-8")
            print(str(json_string))
            val = json.loads(json.dumps(json_string))
            nonce = val['nonce']
            print('nonce: ' + nonce)
TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: I would guess the problem there is `val['nonce']`, you are interpreting a string as a dictionary

Comment: try idjaw's solution

Comment: @MatthewDarnell: `val = json.loads(json.dumps(json_string))` - Why are you calling `dumps`? You're serializing an already-serialized string there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to decode the byte string, so json can load it. Looking at the code for `json.loads`, it has this exception check:

```
if not isinstance(s, str):
        raise TypeError('the JSON object must be str, not {!r}'.format(
                            s.__class__.__name__))
```

If you go in to your interpreter and make a test, you will see the exception is expected when sending a byte string:

```
>>> a = b'abc'
>>> type(a)
<class 'bytes'>
>>> b = b'abc'.decode('utf-8')
>>> type(b)
<class 'str'>
```

So, trying to call `json.load` with `a`:

```
>>> json.loads(a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/json/__init__.py", line 312, in loads
    s.__class__.__name__))
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'
>>>
```

So, your solution in this case is to decode with `utf-8`

```
import json

data = b'{"nonce":"820346305172674795","hash":"CF9558F1AC5AA3F4F3D598BAD50D8E0FD15E536A98095C01AD1BA962BDF342D0E37CF6ED595758B3217CA1986238B10EB729D5C5EBCE1523B41328365E936DBE","encryptedMessage":"ABF47CA76B72388B3CA8F4BF95D199D02835C5AED546CC6A6A35663C312093DB05E3765A00211242770136D7F2391A2A69CCA28B4D9695","signature":"09036C211B6386AD0B1D7EDA14AE4C4C77721916C9AF48E7141049E2773098665776AA4B7CC6E12B4B5BD1FBB3B590F41C6254313BAEBA9293D87769F1A4200468747470733A2F2F3139322E3136382E312E38343A353030302F746F67676C655F646F6F722431"}'

decoded_data = data.decode('utf-8')
json_data = json.loads(decoded_data)
```

Output:

```
u'nonce': u'820346305172674795', u'hash': u'CF9558F1AC5AA3F4F3D598BAD50D8E0FD15E536A98095C01AD1BA962BDF342D0E37CF6ED595758B3217CA1986238B10EB729D5C5EBCE1523B41328365E936DBE', u'encryptedMessage': u'ABF47CA76B72388B3CA8F4BF95D199D02835C5AED546CC6A6A35663C312093DB05E3765A00211242770136D7F2391A2A69CCA28B4D9695', u'signature': u'09036C211B6386AD0B1D7EDA14AE4C4C77721916C9AF48E7141049E2773098665776AA4B7CC6E12B4B5BD1FBB3B590F41C6254313BAEBA9293D87769F1A4200468747470733A2F2F3139322E3136382E312E38343A353030302F746F67676C655F646F6F722431'}
```

Comment: python3 doesnt have data.decode. I have been using codecs.decode(string, "utf-8") and then feeding that to json.loads. No dice

Comment: The answer I provided was all done in Python 3.5. I have no idea what you are talking about.

Comment: I'm accepting this. I have no idea, it definitely did NOT work before. I am quite unfamiliar with python, not sure what I did wrong. Thanks, it works now.