# Python3 : Azure Key Vault Keys, creating RAS key : TypeError

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure, azure-keyvault

Following example in :

https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/tree/master/sdk/keyvault/azure-keyvault-keys

whenever I run the below code :

```
rsa_key = key_client.create_rsa_key("rsa-key-demo", size=2048)
print(rsa_key.name)
print(rsa_key.key_type)
```

The key will be created in my Azure keyVult, however I always get the following error :

> Traceback (most recent call last): File
>   "c:/Users/user/Desktop/azure_keyValut_demo.py", line 152, in rsa_key =
>   key_client.create_rsa_key("rsa-key-demo", size=2048) File
>   "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\azure\core\tracing\decorator.py",
>   line 62, in wrapper_use_tracer return func(*args, **kwargs) # type:
>   ignore File
>   "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\azure\keyvault\keys_client.py",
>   line 131, in create_rsa_key return self.create_key(name,
>   key_type="RSA-HSM" if hsm else "RSA", **kwargs) File
>   "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\azure\core\tracing\decorator.py",
>   line 62, in wrapper_use_tracer return func(*args, **kwargs) # type:
>   ignore File
>   "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\azure\keyvault\keys_client.py",
>   line 96, in create_key
>   **kwargs File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\azure\keyvault\keys_shared_generated\v7_0\operations_key_vault_client_operations.py",
>   line 96, in create_key deserialized = self._deserialize('KeyBundle',
>   response) File
>   "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\msrest\serialization.py",
>   line 1180, in call data = self._unpack_content(response_data,
>   content_type) File
>   "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\msrest\serialization.py",
>   line 1334, in unpack_content return json.loads(data) File
>   "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\json_init.py",
>   line 348, in loads 'not {!r}'.format(s.class.name)) TypeError: the
>   JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not 'method'

I didn't quite understand why that exception is being thrown.

I found this on stackoverflow but still couldn't understand what's going on:

[Why won't python3 load this json string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36804132/why-wont-python3-load-this-json-string)

**The code run successfully with no issues with Python2.7**

**The exception will be thrown for all key operations (create, delete, get)**

**It also happens with all Cryptographic operations**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my test, if we use `msrest` under version 0.6.x, we will get the error.
My test steps are as below

My `requirements.txt`

```
azure-common==1.1.23
azure-core==1.1.1
azure-identity==1.1.0
azure-keyvault-keys==4.0.0
certifi==2019.11.28
cffi==1.13.2
chardet==3.0.4
cryptography==2.8
idna==2.8
isodate==0.6.0
msal==1.0.0
msal-extensions==0.1.3
msrest==0.5.5
oauthlib==3.1.0
portalocker==1.5.2
pycparser==2.19
PyJWT==1.7.1
pywin32==227
requests==2.22.0
requests-oauthlib==1.3.0
six==1.13.0
urllib3==1.25.7
```

My code

```
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential
from azure.keyvault.keys import KeyClient

tenant_id=''
client_id=''
client_secret=''
credential = ClientSecretCredential(tenant_id, client_id, client_secret)
client = KeyClient("https://testkey08.vault.azure.net/", credential)

key = client.create_rsa_key("rsa-key-demo", size=2048)
print(key.name)
print(key.key_type)
```

[image]

So, please update the `merest` to 0.6.x. The detailed steps are as below

1. Create project

```
python -m venv mytestenv # Might be "python3" or "py -3.6" depending on your Python installation
cd mytestenv
source bin/activate      # Linux shells (Bash, ZSH, etc.)
scripts\activate         # Windows shells (PowerShell, CMD)
```

2. install SDK
   My `requirements.txt`

```
azure-common==1.1.23
azure-core==1.1.1
azure-identity==1.1.0
azure-keyvault-keys==4.0.0
certifi==2019.11.28
cffi==1.13.2
chardet==3.0.4
cryptography==2.8
idna==2.8
isodate==0.6.0
msal==1.0.0
msal-extensions==0.1.3
msrest==0.6.10
oauthlib==3.1.0
portalocker==1.5.2
pycparser==2.19
PyJWT==1.7.1
pywin32==227
requests==2.22.0
requests-oauthlib==1.3.0
six==1.13.0
urllib3==1.25.7
xlrd==1.2.0
```

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

3. Code

```
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential
from azure.keyvault.keys import KeyClient

tenant_id=''
client_id=''
client_secret=''
credential = ClientSecretCredential(tenant_id, client_id, client_secret)
client = KeyClient("https://testkey08.vault.azure.net/", credential)

key = client.create_rsa_key("rsa-key-demo", size=2048)
print(key.name)
print(key.key_type)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, I upgraded the package and it works fine.
I'm curious how you were able to figure it out, I'm trying to learn how to debug issues similar to this in future.